# How to programmatically get a diskutil list kind of output

Tags: macos, cocoa, filesystems

I am trying to read the hfs headers so I need to first fopen the Volume disk file like /disk/disk01 ...

diskutil list gives the same output, but how to get that in a cocoa / carbon application?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [DiskArbitration framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/DiscArbitrationFramework/_index.html) for this.